# Could not connect to ZooKeeper using Solr in localhost

Tags: scala, solr, apache-zookeeper

I'm using Solr 6 and I'm trying to populate it.
Here's the **main scala** I put in place :

```
object testChildDocToSolr {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c:\\winutils\\")
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("spark-solr-tester")
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
      .config("spark.default.parallelism", "1")
      .getOrCreate()

    val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
    val collectionName = "testChildDocument"
    val testDf = sparkSession.read.json("./child_documents.json") 
    testDf.printSchema()
    testDf.show()

    val zkHost = "localhost:8983"
    val solrOpts = Map(
      "zkhost" -> zkHost,
      "collection" -> collectionName,
      "gen_uniq_key" -> "true",
      "gen_uniq_child_key" -> "true", 
      "child_doc_fieldname" -> "tags"
    )

    testDf.write.format("solr").options(solrOpts).mode(Overwrite).save()

    // Explicit commit to make sure all docs are visible
    val solrCloudClient = SolrSupport.getCachedCloudClient(zkHost)
    solrCloudClient.commit(collectionName, true, true)

    val solrDf = sparkSession.read.format("solr").options(solrOpts).load()
    solrDf.show()
    sc.stop()
  }

}
```

I'm getting the **error** :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:8983 within 10000 ms
```

It seems that I **can't connect to ZooKeeper** and I don't know why ...

Here's my full log :

```
    [info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\ebelloei\Documents\Ice\DocToSolr\project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to DocToSolr (in build file:/C:/Users/ebelloei/Documents/Ice/DocToSolr/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\ebelloei\Documents\Ice\DocToSolr\target\scala-2.11\classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Packaging C:\Users\ebelloei\Documents\Ice\DocToSolr\target\scala-2.11\doctosolr_2.11-0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Running (fork) Example.testChildDocToSolr 
[info] 2017-12-20 15:09:10,436 [main] WARN  NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[info] 2017-12-20 15:09:11,152 [main] INFO  log  - Logging initialized @2334ms
[info] root
[info]  |-- dates: array (nullable = true)
[info]  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
[info]  |-- status: string (nullable = true)
[info]  |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
[info]  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
[info]  |    |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
[info]  |    |    |-- foo: long (nullable = true)
[info]  |    |    |-- parent: string (nullable = true)
[info]  |-- user: string (nullable = true)
[info] +--------------------+------+--------------------+----+
[info] |               dates|status|                tags|user|
[info] +--------------------+------+--------------------+----+
[info] |[2017-05-02, 2017...|    OK|[[val1,123,a], [v...|   a|
[info] |[2017-04-29, 2017...|    OK|[[val1,789,b], [v...|   b|
[info] +--------------------+------+--------------------+----+
[error] Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:8983 within 10000 ms
[error]     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
[error]     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
[error]     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3936)
[error]     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4806)
[error]     at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.getCachedCloudClient(SolrSupport.scala:190)
[error]     at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.getSolrBaseUrl(SolrSupport.scala:194)
[error]     at com.lucidworks.spark.SolrRelation.insert(SolrRelation.scala:671)
[error]     at solr.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:27)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:472)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:610)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
[error]     at Example.testChildDocToSolr$.main(Main.scala:39)
[error]     at Example.testChildDocToSolr.main(Main.scala)
[error] Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:8983/solr within 10000 ms
[error]     at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:183)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:117)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:107)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.<init>(ZkStateReader.java:226)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ZkClientClusterStateProvider.connect(ZkClientClusterStateProvider.java:131)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.connect(CloudSolrClient.java:631)
[error]     at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.getSolrCloudClient(SolrSupport.scala:168)
[error]     at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.getNewSolrCloudClient(SolrSupport.scala:186)
[error]     at com.lucidworks.spark.util.CacheCloudSolrClient$$anon$1.load(SolrSupport.scala:37)
[error]     at com.lucidworks.spark.util.CacheCloudSolrClient$$anon$1.load(SolrSupport.scala:35)
[error]     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
[error]     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
[error]     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
[error]     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
[error]     ... 24 more
[error] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:8983/solr within 10000 ms
[error]     at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager.waitForConnected(ConnectionManager.java:233)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:175)
[error]     ... 37 more
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error]     at sbt.ForkRun.processExitCode$1(Run.scala:29)
[error]     at sbt.ForkRun.run(Run.scala:38)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5(Defaults.scala:1155)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5$adapted(Defaults.scala:1150)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool.$anonfun$run$1(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:359)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:282)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] Total time: 26 s, completed 20 déc. 2017 15:09:25
1. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
```

And my **Zoo.cfg** :

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5

# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/data
# NOTE: Solr defaults the dataDir to <solrHome>/zoo_data

# the port at which the clients will connect
# clientPort=8983
# NOTE: Solr sets this based on zkRun / zkHost params
```

I'm really new to this and don't know if I'm missing something evident because I can't find someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

You're giving the Solr host and port as the zookeeper connection details. Zookeeper and Solr runs on separate ports as they are separate daemons. If you're running zookeeper externally from Solr (i.e. a dedicated Zookeeper installation), the default port is `2181` (so `localhost:2181`). If you're using the one embedded in Solr, the port is Solr's port + 1000, usually `9983` (and thus, `localhost:9983`).

Comment: I'm using the one embedded in Solr, so I try to change my zkHost to : val zkHost = "localhost:9983" , but still the same issue. I change the client port in my zoo.cfg file to 8983, could it be a problem ?

Comment: Solr runs on 8983 by default, so that won't work. Run `netstat -a` to show which ports are being listened to.

Comment: Ok so I changed my zoo.cfg to 2181 to avoid more issue, I can see the port 8983 is issued but nothing much, could zookeeper not be launched ? I'm sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: Have you actually [started Solr in cloud mode](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/getting-started-with-solrcloud.html)?

Comment: No i'm trying to use it locally , I strat solr like this : solr start -p 8983 -f

Comment: If you're not starting Solr in cloud mode, there will be no Zookeeper running or any use of Zookeeper. Solr uses Zookeeper to coordinate internally between nodes. When running in standalone node, no connection is made to Zookeeper and no embedded zookeeper instance is started. If you're not running in cloud mode (which you can do locally - the "cloud" mode is a term for running as a cluster), you're shouldn't request a cloud client when creating the client either.

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you add this to your answer, and if you have time, just explain how should I do, if I want to do it only locally ? I will validate your answer and delete my comments.