# Getting org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: caused by empty node name specified @1

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Getting `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path string "//10.52.21.4:8021/solr" caused by empty node name specified @1` while trying to connect to solr client.

Full Logs:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path string "//10.52.21.4:8021/solr" caused by empty node name specified @1
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:171)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.<init>(ZkStateReader.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ZkClientClusterStateProvider.connect(ZkClientClusterStateProvider.java:140)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.connect(CloudSolrClient.java:383)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(CloudSolrClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.request(CloudSolrClient.java:793)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:178)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:195)
```

I am getting the error while trying to execute below block of code:

```
String solrUrl="http://10.52.21.4:8021/solr/";
ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
CollectionAdminResponse response = ( CollectionAdminResponse ) request.process( new CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost( solrUrl ).build() );
fields = ( ArrayList<String> ) response.getResponse().get( "collections" );
```

Anybody please help with the problem.

Comment: What's the code you're using to connect? What's the path/URL you've specified?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have updated the question with the code and URL. You can check.

Comment: You're attempting to use the Solr http endpoint as the connection information to zookeeper. When you're creating the Solr cloud client, you give it the connection information to your zookeeper instances, not to the HTTP endpoint of Solr itself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908373/could-not-connect-to-zookeeper-using-solr-in-localhost/47908439#47908439